# usage of system function in cpp program

Tags: c++, c

Please explain the syntax of:
system(const char *command);

I want to use this function for running the command on unix sytem.
I need to execute(automate) several test cases with the same command but,they also have other input values which are different.how do I reuse this code for all the test-cases.

Comment: cpp is the c pre-processor, not C++

Answer (score 3):

```
int main()
{
    char *base = "./your_testcase " ;
    char aux[50] = "./your_testcase " ;
    char *args[] = {"arg1" ,"arg2" ,"arg3"};
    int nargs = 3;

    for(i=0;i < nargs;i++)
    {
        /* Add arg to the end of the command */
        strcat(aux,args[i]) ;
        /* Call command with parameter */
        system(aux);
        /* Reset aux to just the system call with no parameters */
        strcpy(aux,base);
    }
}
```

Comment: better: snprintf( aux, 50, "%s %s", base, args[ i ]);

Answer (score 3):

Keep in mind that calling system is the same as calling fork and execl. That mean you need to be aware of things like open socket descriptors and file descriptors. I once had a problem with a TCP/IP socket dying on a server because a client was calling system which created a new socket connection to the server that was not being serviced.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how the syntax can be a problem:

```
system( "foo" );
```

executes the program called foo, via your preferred shell.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a command line for each invokation, then pass those command lines into system() one a time.

Answer (score 0):

See also the question:
'How to call an external program with parameters?;

[How to call an external program with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486087/how-to-call-an-external-program-with-parameters/486409#486409)

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid use of the system() function, here is a link to why this might be a [bad idea](http://www.webinmind.net/bpc.html#six)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, how to implement system() command in c++

```
#include <cstdlib>
 
 int main()
 {
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Maybe you should read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) before using `system("pause");`

Answer (score 0):

```
system(const char *command)
```

Is used to execute a command on the command line of the current operating system. It is generally not the best idea to use this because the commands are platform specific. Keep in mind that `const char *command` is a string and you can pass any string value as a parameter and it will be sent to the command line.

Answer (score -1):

i think Anter is interested in a example:

for instance to remove a file in a directory:

system("/bin/rm -rf /home/ederek/file.txt");

Comment: can somebody explain why i was given a -1

Comment: I didn't down vote, but why do you have the recursive option for a file?