# How to have excatly the same effect as using "run..." from StartMenu to call a program with command line arguments in C++/CLI?

Tags: c++-cli, command-line-arguments

in a C++/CLI program I'm using

```
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start("D:\\users\\Z\\project1\\Sent_0.93\\plotCon\\tester\\bin\\Debug\\tester.exe","20 D:\users\Z\project1\Bright20");
```

to call the tester.exe, which is another project written in C# (but I think it doesn't matter here)
then something strange happens now. If I debug the C# program with command line arguments given in project setting, it's working as expected. If I call this C# program from Start menu->run, it's also working fine.
but with the given line above, the C# program is started, but behaves quite wierd.
So the question is why and how to change the C++ code to make its calling have exactly the same effect as I call from "Start->run"

Thank you

Comment: tried also the more complete way like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486087/how-to-call-an-external-program-with-parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your string for the `arguments` parameter -- `"20 D:\users\Z\project1\Bright20"` has embedded escape characters, you need to use double-backslash as you correctly did for the `fileName` parameter:

```cpp
System::Diagnostics::Process::Start(
    "D:\\users\\Z\\project1\\Sent_0.93\\plotCon\\tester\\bin\\Debug\\tester.exe",
    "20 D:\\users\\Z\\project1\\Bright20"
);  //    ^^     ^^ ^^        ^^
```

Comment: yes, exactly. Actually I found out this stupid mistake several minutes after posting... but I can't answer my own question since i have too little reputation points   Thanks all the same