# Can't launch website in C++

Tags: c++

Trying to launch a website in Visual C++ 2010 Express, every researched solution has not worked. So I gather I need more in-depth assistance. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
char name[240];


cout<<"\nHello, Please enter your name: ";
cin.getline(name,240);
cout<<"\nHello "<<name <<", your ID has been confirmed!";


cout<<"\nContinuing to launch website 'xyz' now.";
//  system("C:\\Program%Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
ShellExecute, TEXT("open"), TEXT(c:\\program                                     
    files\\google\\chrome\\application\\chrome.exe), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL;
goto end;

end:

cout<<"\n\nProgram completed, Pess any key to exit. ";

_getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, starting with reading the [about](http://stackoverflow.com/about) is a good starter for this forum since it has quite a few good pointers. :)

Comment: You need to say what "doesn't work" means... but check your quotes in your TEXT macro..

Answer (score 2):

Like this.

```
ShellExecute(NULL, TEXT("open"), TEXT("c:\\program files\\google\\chrome\\application\\chrome.exe"), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

You had missing parens, missing double quotes and quite possibly spurious characters between 'program' and 'files' in your path. You also had a missing parameter to ShellExecute.

Reading a book and learning a minimum of C++ syntax would be a good idea. These are very basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" http://heise.de");
```

works for me.
See [How to call an external program with parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486087/how-to-call-an-external-program-with-parameters)