# Is there a way to simply call multiple cpp out files from a gpu?

Tags: c++, cuda

I was wondering whether this is possible? Could someone please point out if I'm wrong anywhere? I'm a complete newbie to CUDA.

```
__global__ void run_multiple_cpp(int *n, int *result){
    int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < n){
        result[i] = system("//path to a.out" -parameters[i])
    }
}

int main(void){
    // Get input here,
    // kernel call which splits the input as shown above
    return 0;
}
```

My question is whether this is possible **without requiring to write the CPP file CUDA friendly.** I've tried using **__device__** and **__host__** flags but my application is too big to be modified to support CUDA.

The operation above is always based on different set of inputs - I've tried CPU multithreading but I need to run this application for a large set of inputs. Hence I asked.

Comment: Why a negative reputation? I'm simply asking whether is this possible.

Comment: didnt downvote, though questions along the line "Does X work?" are usually best answered by simply trying it out. Did you maybe actually wanted to ask "Why does it not work?" ? In that case i guess much more information would be required to help you

Comment: My question is how to use "system" in the kernel. Look at the first answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703721/how-to-execute-another-exe-from-a-c-program-in-windows    - I wanted to ask whether that works on GPU as well.

Comment: thats not really clear from your question and even then you should show what you tried (see also [mcve]). The code you posted here will fail to reasons completely unrelated to calling `system`. you got the arguments wrong, `"//path to a.out" -parameters[i]` ... there is no autoconcatenation of strings and `//path to a.out"` is of course not a valid path...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason GPUs are fast is they contain many small and simple processors so can perform many simple tasks in parallel.
High level operations like calling `system` are completely unavailable on the GPU. In order to take advantage of the power of the GPU you will need to rewrite your code for CUDA/OpenCL/Metal etc.

If you can't modify your program to run on the GPU you might be able to take advantage of the CPU's [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) features and still achieve a (smaller) speedup, this may also be a stepping stone to GPU processing as making your code CPU SIMD friendly will also likely make porting to the GPU easier.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486087/how-to-call-an-external-program-with-parameters ---- So basically I cannot implement the high level operation "system", like in the mentioned example, on GPU.

Comment: No you can't, simple operations only on the gpu